# Google Maps API - Get New Center Coordinates after map is moved

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API to display a map, but I now need to capture the centre coordinators if the user moves the map. I'm after the new lat/long of the new centre of the map after it has been moved.

Looking at the [Maps Events docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) I can see a few options here:

```
 center_changed
 dragend
```

that I could potentially move. I've tried both but can't get the syntax right and not sure how to retrieve the centre lat/long. Here's my latest attempt

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    console.log("current latitude is: "+latitude);
    console.log("current longitude is: "+longitude);
});
```

but I get an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.latLng.lat')` when this runs.

Can anyone tell me what the most approrpriate event to use here and how I can get the new centre co-ordinatates when the map has changed by the user dragging it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the center values when it changes, use the ['center_changed'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.center_changed) event:

> **center_changed**
>   Arguments:  None
>   This event is fired when the map center property changes.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
  var center = this.getCenter();
  var latitude = center.lat();
  var longitude = center.lng();
  console.log("current latitude is: " + latitude);
  console.log("current longitude is: " + longitude);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/afk8ewrm/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
    var center = this.getCenter();
    var latitude = center.lat();
    var longitude = center.lng();
    console.log("current latitude is: " + latitude);
    console.log("current longitude is: " + longitude);
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up changing this to the `dragend` event as the center_changed was creating tens of updates as you moved the map, when I just needed the final centre lat/long when the map had finished moving